# Command line: crop PDF to paper size (Fedora)

Tags: scripting, pdf

Tools like `pdfcrop` (from `texlive`) are great but they seem to be too focused on removing margins/white space. I'm trying to crop a set of letter pages (8.5x11 inches) to a size of 6x9 inches. I want this measurement to start from the top left of the page; thus the 6x9 I want is the top left 6x9 segment of the original paper, not a centered 6x9 or a 6x9 based on any margins. How can I do this via the command line? I'm on Fedora 23, so something like `pdftk` is unavailable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with Ghostscript.

```
  gs \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -o marked.pdf \
  -c "[/CropBox [54 54 1314 810] /PAGES pdfmark" \
  -f original.pdf
```

The cropbox must be calculated with the resolution of your PDF, reference is the bottom left corner. See also [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158295/what-dimensions-do-the-coordinates-in-pdf-cropbox-refer-to).

Comment: Thank you SO much; I had found a Ghostscript solution earlier, but I see now that there was an error in the command I used (an extra " before \PAGES). I had to change it to [0 144 432 792] for my purposes, but your answer (and the QA) were tremendously helpful!